# gitbook (Markdown/AsciiDoc) center text under/below images

Tags: markdown, asciidoc, gitbook

Center 1 image and text to the full width.
https://coderwall.com/p/iftc1q/centered-text-and-images-in-github-markdown

plugin that does the same 
https://github.com/todvora/gitbook-plugin-image-captions

AsciiDocTOR discussion on the issue: 
https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/857

I try to use gitbook to do a ... book. 
But multiple times I have 4 images on single row/line i.e side by side to each other. With a caption/title/desctription which needs to be centered under each image. 
Is there any way this can be achieved with some html/css trickery mixed into? 
Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way in Markdown.

It can be done in AsciiDoc with tables in two ways:

- Put the title/text at the same column on the next row.
- Put the image and the title/text in the same cell than align that cell content vertically and horizontally as you wish.

Remove table borders with "frame" and "grid" attributes.